# A PHP Error was encountered :Message: Undefined property: NewsController::$validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

i got this erorr :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: NewsController::$validation

Filename: controllers/NewsController.php

Line Number: 169
```

> > Fatal error: Call to a member function _set_fields() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\News\application\controllers\NewsController.php on line 169

..

```php
class NewsController extends CI_Controller{
// num of records per page
private $limit = 10;

    function News(){
    parent::Controller();

    // load library
    $this->load->library(array('table','validation'));

    // load helper
    $this->load->helper('url');

    // load model
    $this->load->model('NewsModel','',TRUE);
    }
   function _set_fields(){
    $fields['id'] = 'id';
    $fields['title'] = 'title';
    $fields['image'] = 'image';
    $fields['discreption'] = 'discreption';

    $this->validation->_set_fields($fields);
    }
        // validation rules
   function _set_rules(){
    $rules['title'] = 'trim|required';
    $rules['image'] = 'trim|required';
    $rules['discreption'] = 'trim|required';

    $this->validation->set_rules($rules);

    $this->validation->set_message('required', '* required');
    $this->validation->set_message('isset', '* required');
    $this->validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
  }

 }
```

Comment: Your object $this->validation must be null.

Comment: Are you sure you can load libraries using an array? Why you keep calling `parent::Controller();` (saw this in another question of yours)

Comment: Are you sure library's name is validation?? just checking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because  `_set_fields()` is not a member of `validation` library you are calling.

May it helps

use `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

instead of `$this->load->library('validation')`

Now replace `$this->validation` by `$this->form_validation`

**user guide has better explanation** [codeigniter-form_validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

let me know if i understood you wrongly.

**EDIT**

if you want to keep values in input fields after error of `form_validation` and sending back to input page, then use `set_value` **in your view** like

`<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name');?>">` for input `name="name"`

**EDIT1**

```
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
  // load library,helper and models here. so you can use them all over inside this class
 $this->load->library('form_validation');    // load library
 $this->load->library('table');
 $this->load->helper('url');// load helper
   // load model
 $this->load->model('NewsModel');
}

 function news(){
  }
    //and other codes
```

Comment: have u read documentention? I dont thnk they ve _set_fields like function.corect me if i m wrng.

Comment: yeah man you'r right and i have used set_value()rather than  _set_fields but i'm still got that damn error :Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: NewsController::$form_validation

Filename: controllers/NewsController.php

Line Number: 169                                                  Fatal error: Call to a member function set_value() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\News\application\controllers\NewsController.php on line 169

Comment: use set_value() in your view not in your controller.

Comment: ok man thanks i 'll try it , but can you plz give me your contact that i can review with you the result of this application

Comment: hey Nabin ,i tried it but i got this result 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 731
with this result :
Add news 
ID   
Title*  
Image*  
discreption*  
           save
           
Back to list of News

Comment: At first I want you to go to documentation site and read form_validation section and compare your code with that.please..
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: i read it man and i fixed my code , and it respond with a web page loading my view & this error message 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 731
so i asked your contact to send you this web page as print screen